# Erlang/Elixir guards and arity

Tags: erlang, elixir, arity, pattern-guards

Is there a way to see a function's guards without seeing the source code?

Given an example function (in Elixir):

```
def divide(x, y) when y != 0 do
  x / y
end
```

How would one figure out that there is a guard on divide/2 without access to the source code, and how would one find info about that guard or what that guard expects for a pattern match?

I was watching a talk by Chris McCord (creator of Elixir's Phoenix Framework) from Ruby Conf 2014. During the talk Chris was describing guards and someone asked if there was a way to inspect a function that would show the function's guards.

This is the question from the talk:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5kYmOyJjGDM&t=5188

The question is asked shortly after the video's t= time.

Comment: Just curious--what's the use case here?  Shouldn't guard conditions help you to avoid writing bad code?  So if you violate a guard condition, re-write your code.

Comment: I, too, was just curious. One use case I can imagine is a guarded  function that (for instance) only allows numbers between 1 and 10. How is one to know that? The answer is surely "Look at the docs" or "Look at the source code", but I was hoping that there would be an answer such as "Just use the ```SomeModule.show_guards/1``` function and pass the function of interest".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently it is not possible to introspect this information without looking at the source.

Comment: You can look at the generated BEAM code. :-) Just joking.

Comment: There is now a way to see the guards and arity of a function without looking at the source code. Elixir 1.5 introduces `Exception.blame/3` which is invoked upon certain errors (for example a `FunctionClauseError`). `Exception.blame/3` displays precisely the information in this question (and more). Erlang/OTP 20 is required. Check it out here: https://elixir-lang.org/blog/2017/07/25/elixir-v1-5-0-released/

Answer (score 0):

If there is debug info in the beam file a library can be created that parses it and get you what you require without looking into source code. Here is one example in Erlang how you can get the arities of a function.

```
1> GetArities = 
  fun(Module, FunName) ->
    {ok,{_,[{abstract_code,{_,AC}}]}} = beam_lib:chunks(Module,[abstract_code]),
    lists:foldl(
      fun({function, _Line, Fun, Arity, _Clauses}, FunArities) when Fun == FunName ->
            [Arity | FunArities];
          (_, FunArities) ->
            FunArities
      end, [], AC)
  end.

2> GetArities(fact,fact).
[1,0]
```

For a sample module named fact with 2 functions also named fact, you can get the above output.

Clauses in abstract code will have guards with atom op. Those can also be retrieved.